# Prepositions with the verb "ask": "ask questions from," "ask a question to"

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

"What questions do they ask a communication trainer?" or "What questions do they ask from a communication trainer?" Also, I know "She asked me a question" is what's generally used but just have a little doubt about, "She asked a question to me" Is it correct to use 'to' as a preposition here?

Answer (score 2):

"from" is not used with 'ask a question'. The normal usage is "ask a question", but you can also say "ask a question of". So:

> What questions do they ask a communication trainer?
>
> What questions do they ask of a communication trainer?

are both OK. Some variants allowed are:

> What questions do they pose to a communication trainer?
>
> What questions do they put to a communication trainer?

You can say:

> What do they ask from a communication trainer?

but that sentence **is not about questions**. "What do they ask from..." means "What do they expect from...", i.e. what to they expect a communications trainer to do.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. If you could also help me clear the latter part of my doubt, which is, whether or not to use 'to' as a preposition in "She asked a question to me."